# Derby ERROR 54038: Maximum depth of nested triggers was exceeded

Tags: sql, database, derby

I am trying to fire a trigger which sets owner_notif_sta to null after an update or insertion to owner_notif_sta if owner_id is null. Both owner_id and owner_notif_sta are from the same table.

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_owner
AFTER UPDATE OF owner_notif_sta ON risk
REFERENCING OLD AS EXISTING
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    UPDATE risk SET owner_notif_sta = NULL
    WHERE owner_id IS NULL;
```

The update I tried to fire:

```
UPDATE RISK SET owner_notif_sta = 'helloo' WHERE risk_id = 'ICT123';
```

and owner_id was null (not populated when i fired the update)

and I received the following error:
ERROR 54038: Maximum depth of nested triggers was exceeded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing the `UPDATE` statement slightly to exclude rows that already have `owner_notif_sta` as null:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_owner
AFTER UPDATE OF owner_notif_sta ON risk
REFERENCING OLD AS EXISTING
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    UPDATE risk 
       SET owner_notif_sta = NULL
     WHERE owner_id IS NULL
       AND owner_notif_sta IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: thank you. I tried that but I think that Derby does not support If else statements.

Comment: I edited my answer.  I think it's much simpler, and it should work.  Just add `AND owner_notif_sta IS NOT NULL` at the end of the `UPDATE` statement in the trigger.  It should prevent the recursive trigger calls.

Comment: I should add that, because this is a row trigger, I'm surprised that your update statement doesn't have a `where` clause on a key or id column (e.g.: `where id = existing.id)`.  I would expect the update to be limited to a single row, but I'm not seeing that.  That maybe something else that you need to look at.